# How to create 3 squares from this arrangement of matches?

Tags: puzzle

There's a matches riddle that I can't quite solve.
Given the following layout (a 4 matches plus sign connected to a 8 matches square):

```
 __|__
 __|__
|     |
|__ __|
```

I need to transform this into **exactly** 3 squares by moving 5 matches only.
It's driving me crazy, so if you know how to solve this, please share.

Comment: Do you mean the final result has to be **exactly** 3 squares, or does the final result only have to **contain** 3 squares?

Comment: @Zeb I meant exactly. I fixed the question to show this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
__|__
  |__ __
  |     |
  |__ __|
```

```
__|__
  |__ __
  |   __|
   __ __|
```

```
__|__
  |__ __
  |   __|
     |__|
```

```
__|__
  |__|__
      __|
     |__|
```

```
__
__|__
  |__|
      __|
     |__|
```

```
 __
|__|__
   |__|
       __
      |__|
```

Or do you mean?

```
   __|__
   __|__
  |     |
  |__ __|
```

```
   __|__
   __|__
  |__   |
  |   __|
```

```
   __|__
   __|__
  |__|  |
      __|
```

```
   __|__
   __|__|
  |__|  
      __|
```

```
   __
   __|__
   __|__|
  |__|  
        |
```

```
   __
  |__|__
   __|__|
  |__|
```

Comment: it seems like there are 2 missing matches in your answer... And yes it should be exactly 5 moves.

Comment: I miss interpreted your post. I think this fixes it.

Comment: the second one is the correct one. Thanks! I was trying to solve this for a long time but kept missing this solution. Was this the result of trail and error, or did you come up with a way to systematically solve this?

Comment: Realizing you can only move 5 sticks really limits which ones you can move. Like creating a new square from nothing would use up 4 moves! Also, you can't get exactly 3 squares if two of them share a side. Keeping these things in mind really limited what could be done. I'll leave both answers up. The other one is a nice puzzle too :)

Answer (score 0):

By moving only three matches (the right hand of the plus sign and the two parallel matches below it), you can write a $4$, a $0$ and a $1$ : you get your three squares and you economize two moves !